# Comparator on Logisim

Tags: logisim, digital-comparator

Currently working on an elevator circuit. I am using 4-bits to represent the floor that the elevator is on, and I need a way of comparing this value to the floor that the user wants to get to.  I am currently trying to use a 4-bit comparator to solve this, but I can't figure out how to connect the 4 floor bits into the comparator without getting an improper width error. I feel like there must be an easy way to do this, but I am new to Logisim and not totally sure how to make this connection. To clarify, the four bits representing the floor are not directly compatible with the comparator because I used 4 different registers with 1-bit outputs.

If there is no other way I can just make a comparator from gates but obviously that is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the splitter component](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.3.0/libs/base/splitter.html) to combine four one-bit signals into a four-bit bus:

[image]